# Odata query in power bi fails on computed column

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi, odata

I've been following the tutorial here:
[Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/sample-pipelines-pass-rate-trend?view=azure-devops&tabs=odata)

I can get the odata uri parsed together just fine and get a json repsonse from azure devops that looks exactly like I expect.  However when I take that same uri and use it as the odata source in Power Bi, I get the error:

> Details: "OData: The property 'PartiallySuccessfulRate' does not exist on type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Analytics.Model.PipelineRun'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type or mark the type as open type."

If I remove them, the query works fine in powerbi.
Is there a way to make powerbi accept the computed columns?  Or do I have to do the calculation in powerbi?

Answer (score 0):

I would rather to these small calculations in power bi. I use most of the time Odata query for Dynamics as well. My main purpose of Oata query is to fetch only required data and not like millions of records.
Once this purpose is solved, I let powerbi do some calculations for me.

In this way it is easier for my Team to collaborate as well so that they can update/change as easily as they can.

Comment: Ok, Maybe I'll give that a try instead.  Thanks for the info.